# Can $n!+1$ be a square number when n is a big number?

Tags: number-theory

To be specific, $n$ and $a$ are positive integers. 
I guess the equation $n!=a^2-1$ just have three solutions. 
There are $n=4,a=5;n=5,a=11;n=7,a=71$. 
How to prove it? Or my guess is wrong.

Comment: This is [Brocard's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem).  The solution is unknown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested in the comments:  This is a (fairly) well known open problem.  It is known as [Brocard's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard's_problem). The $abc$ conjecture would show that there are only finitely many solutions, though I do not believe it would establish that the known list is complete.